# Free, portable, Windows email client with auto-correct spelling

Tags: windows, gratis, email-client, portable, spell-checker

I am almost desperate enough to use MS Outlook, but would strongly prefer something portable.

**Must have**

- Gratis
- Windows (10)
- Support multiple email addresses
- [update] auto-correct spell checker

**Nice to have**

- plays well with Gmail (and my own server)
- large user base and good support
- support for GPG encryption
- other security features
- fairly standard look/feel
- plugins

---

It looks like MS Outlook is no longer free. I am experimenting with Windows 10's built-in Mail app.

Answer (score 3):

[Portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/) has a portable version of [Thunderbird](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable) that should do the job nicely.

- Gratis - **Yes**
- Windows (10) - **Yes & 7/8**
- Support Multiple email addresses/accounts - **Yes**
- Plays well with GMail and others - **Yes**
- Large User Base **Yes** *both portable apps and Thunderbird have large user base and active communities*
- GPG **Yes** *"You can also add in GPG and Enigmail to encrypt and sign your email"*
- Spell Check, etc. **Yes**
- Fairly standard look & feel:
  [image]

Comment: Ooopsies!! Sorry, Steve, I am already using ThunderbIrd (+1), I just phrased the question badly.  I asked in the title for an auto-correct spell checker, but forgot to put it in the list of must have features. I have been using TB since Qualcomm scrapped Eudroa, but the lack of this features is now aggravating me so much that I am willing to switch. Even (shudder) to MS Outlook, if I can't get a good portable client (portable because I reinstall Windows every few months). Any ideas?